# set JTextField Size according to text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

In my program i have to make `JTextField` Dynamically when `JButton` pressed. And i have to set `JTextField` size according to text inside in `JTextArea`.
The process is whenever i typed any message in `JTextArea` and pressed `JButton` it show that message inside `JTextField`. And `JTextField` size is according to the text that i want to display in `JTextArea`.
this is my code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ThirdApplication {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel_2;
    private JTextArea SendText;
    private int y=20;
    private JTextField DisplayText;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WebLookAndFeel.install();
                    ThirdApplication window = new ThirdApplication();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ThirdApplication() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 614, 649);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 608, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 621, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 534, 608, 87);
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                panel_2.revalidate();
                panel_2.repaint();
                DisplayText = new JTextField();
                DisplayText.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                DisplayText.setEditable(false);
                DisplayText.setBounds(10,y,0,0);
                DisplayText.setText(SendText.getText());
                panel_2.add(DisplayText,"width 179, height 40,wrap");
                DisplayText.setColumns(10);
                y=y+38;
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 15));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(509, 23, 89, 40);
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 486, 65);
        panel_1.add(scrollPane);

        SendText = new JTextArea();
        SendText.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(SendText);

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(0, 0, 608, 534);
        panel.add(scrollPane_1);

        panel_2 = new JPanel();
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap"));

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense (to me). 1) Why would you try to display multiple lines of text in a JTextField which can only display a single line of text? 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your names are correct, others are not. Be consistent!!! 3) Why are you still using a null layout. Did you not read the comments from your last question. 4) When you post code use standard JDK classes. We can't execute your code because we don't have the classes you use. 5) Don't forget to respond to questions when people take the time to help.

Comment: Instead of jtextfield can I use other component.  So how can I use give some examples.